# What is the difference between Page Subscriber and Page Likes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-like, facebook-subscriptions

I run a page and noticed that I have 35k likes, but only 18 subscribers. What is the difference?

> [image: likes vs subbers]

I've reviewed some other pages and did not find a link to subscribe to them.

Comment: Do clicking or hovering over the little question marks on the pictured page say anything useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Facebook spokesperson quoted in [this Marketing Land article](http://marketingland.com/subscribe-for-pages-being-tested-by-facebook-16977):

> We are currently testing the ability to subscribe to Pages with a
>   small group. This feature allows people to receive updates from Pages
>   without liking the Page. We have no further details to share at this
>   time.